# Make Radial Device(Surface Dial) to AutoSelect Winform at start

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/RadialController/cs/winforms/Form1.cs) from GitHub. We can easily add a menu for Radial Device like below

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Input;
    
namespace RadialControllerWinForms
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      RadialController radialController;

      private void CreateController_and_menu()
      {            
        IRadialControllerInterop interop = (IRadialControllerInterop)System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(typeof(RadialController));
        Guid guid = typeof(RadialController).GetInterface("IRadialController").GUID;    
        radialController = interop.CreateForWindow(this.Handle, ref guid); 
    
        radialController.Menu.Items.Add(RadialControllerMenuItem.CreateFromKnownIcon("Ruler", RadialControllerMenuKnownIcon.Ruler));
      }   
   }
}
```

this works fine, i can capture surface dial's input in winform using surface dial. but everytime when winform starts i need to select winform ("Ruler") from surface dial's menu. 
Can we make it to auto select "Ruler" without choosing from surface dial's menu ?
somehow getting 'attention' of the device in form load event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that easily. See the line below:

`radialController.Menu.SelectMenuItem(radialController.Menu[index_of_ruler_in_the_menu]);`

For example, if your ruler is the last element in the `radialController.Menu` then you can get its index as follows:

`int index_of_ruler_in_the_menu =  radialController.Menu.Items.Count - 1;`